# Software compatible alternative to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sbc

Because Raspberry Pi's are hard to get nowadays, I'm looking for an alternative single board computer.

I've seen several sites that list all kinds of alternatives, but those websites don't talk about the thing that is most important for me: software compatibility.

Ideally, I want to be able to pull an SD card out of a Raspberry Pi, put it in the alternative SBC and turn it on. But maybe that's too much to ask. It would already be very nice if I can add a few drivers to my Raspberry Pi OS installation and then be able move the SD card between the Raspberry Pi and the other SBC back and forth.

What single board computer is the most compatible with Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RockPi](https://rockpi.org/) are widely in stock, better performing single board computers. They do generally support most RPi Hats, with exceptions suck as PoE Hats.

They do cost more than RPi 4, but have generally better and faster hardware.

The RockPi has an RK3399 SoC arm64 CPU, roughly 50% faster to twice as fast as RPi4/3 and is binary compatible for applications. RockPi will not run Rasperberry Pi OS, but [have many more options](https://wiki.radxa.com/Rock4/downloads).